# Reassign Trackpad Gestures?

Tags: spaces, trackpad, magic-trackpad, multi-touch, customization

The current behavior for an upward four-finger swipe on the trackpad is to move all Windows to the side and display your desktop.  I personally have no use for this since I keep absolutely nothing on my desktop.   Is there a way to reassign this gesture to something else?

For instance, I'd like to reassign it to Activate Spaces, since I'm a heavy Spaces user.

I'd prefer a non-third party solution to this, if such a solution exists within the bowels of OSX somewhere.  If not, a third-party solution will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible a duplicate, but of course [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?page_id=1722)

Comment: duplicate of which question?  I couldn't find any "related" that asked what I'm asking.

I'll have a look at BetterTouchTool if that's my only option, but I'd much prefer to have non-3rd party solution, if possible (question updated to say as much).